# Page layout not in accordance with pdf printout

Tags: margins

For my thesis, the rule for page layout is determined as:

```
\usepackage[lmargin=1.5in, rmargin=1.0in,tmargin=1.0in,bmargin=1.0in]{geometry}
```

But when I compile to produce PDF and take a print out and measure with a ruler, I find the left is short by 0.1 inch, that is 1.4in and the right is more by 0.1 inch.

Is this normal when we take a printout or am I defining the boundary incorrectly ?

Comment: i've found that not all printers are adjusted precisely, so before trying to modify any input code, try another printer to see if the results are the same.

Comment: @barbarabeeton : yes its varies from printer to printer.